# Matrix identification

Tags: matrices, terminology, applications

Is there any name for a square, symmetric matrix, created in the following format:

$$M_{i,j} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
i + j & i \neq j\\ 
0 & i = j
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $i, j$ start with 1. In particular I am looking whether there are any interesting properties and applications this matrix. I tried to search through [this list of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices), but nothing looks like mine.

Comment: I don't know, is there something you want to prove about such matrices?

Comment: @dREaM actually I need to find probabilities for a mixed nash equilibrium from payoffs created by this matrix. Because I think that this question is too big to be asked here, I would rather try to look at the matrix and whether is has some interesting properties that I can use to solve my task. The matrix is easy to describe, so I believe it falls into some well-known type

Comment: It is a Metzler and a hollow matrix.

Comment: it seems to be almost a Hankel matrix (the problem is on the diagonal). You can write your matrix as a sum of a Hankel matrix and a diagonal matrix.